# CMS vs homebrew system for implementing an image slideshow

Tags: architecture, development-approach

There is a basic website (homepage and 5 subpages) with static content, we want to add something like a slideshow of current offers with custom images that would change every month. We also want to include an image gallery with effects like Lightbox.

The person who is going to add/modify/delete the images in the two new modules doesn't want to deal with FTP. According to your experience, should we install a CMS (Joomla/Drupal) for this or just create a our own basic image management system to upload/select/delete the images?

Comment: Let me know if my edits changed the intent of your question.

Comment: @Anna Lear It's ok! thanks! English is not my native language :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the simple nature of your site and the limited CMS-type needs, I would not implement a full CMS and just create a simple, upload/modify/delete page for the monthly offers.

If you plan or expect more CMS-type activities to begin taking place in the future you might want to consider setting up a CMS though.

Also consider that training the user. Your custom built offer-updater would most likely be much simpler for the end-user, less complexity.

**Edit**
Implementing a full CMS would most likely take a good bit more time to setup raising the cost to your client/company.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it might be worth it if the CMS has features (in terms of display and layout and themes and such) that would save you coding time (assuming custom-code is your alternative). Plus, they are likely to be fixed/updated/featured-added by someone else so you don't have to do any of that. You lose control of the code-base and you have to maintaint the config and installation, but it might be worth it as a time-saver.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably vote for a pretty basic slide uploader/downloader. If you are dealing with someone who can't hack FTP (and presumably update teh codes), they need it nice and simple.

If you want to avoid doing this entirely, I would look at using a photo hosting service like flickr to handle images and some quick little custom script to grab a set of tagged images off their RSS and display the offers.

Answer (score 0):

Is creating a photo gallery in a tool like Picasa or Flickr an option? They have options for sharing as well, see: [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=20053) & [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/help/sharing/#2182) ... and you don't have to re-invent the wheel.

HTH,

KM